# Create a different dictionary from an existing dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary in python which is of format

```
dict = {
                    'p_id':         254,
                    's_id':           1,
                    'object_cnt':     4,

                    'type0':          0,
                    'address0':       65500,
                    'size0':          2,
                    'value0':         23.4,

                    'type1':          1,
                    'address1':       65535,
                    'size1':          2,
                    'value1':         45.7,

                    'type2':          2,
                    'address2':       65,
                    'size2':          0,
                    'value2':         1,

                    'type3':          3,
                    'address3':       535,
                    'size3':          0,
                    'value3':         0,                                                            
}
```

Since the object_cnt is 4, there will four objects in this dictionary.

```
                       'type0':          0,
                    'address0':       65500,
                       'size0':          2,
                      'value0':         23.4,
```

The above can be considered as one object. I want to create a dictionary of form

```
new_dict = {
                    '65500' : (2,23.4)
                    '65535' : (2,45)
                    '65'    : (0,1)
                    '535'   : (0,0)
          }
#address of a object as key and (size_object,value_object) as value
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string formatting:

```
res = {d['address%s' % i]: [d['size%s' %i], d['value%s' % i]] for i in range(d['object_cnt'])}
```

Output:

```
{65: [0, 1], 535: [0, 0], 65500: [2, 23.4], 65535: [2, 45.7]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a  = {
                    'p_id':         254,
                    's_id':           1,
                    'object_cnt':     4,

                    'type0':          0,
                    'address0':       65500,
                    'size0':          2,
                    'value0':         23.4,

                    'type1':          1,
                    'address1':       65535,
                    'size1':          2,
                    'value1':         45.7,

                    'type2':          2,
                    'address2':       65,
                    'size2':          0,
                    'value2':         1,

                    'type3':          3,
                    'address3':       535,
                    'size3':          0,
                    'value3':         0,                                                            
}
n = a['object_cnt']
new_dict = dict()
for i in range(n):
    new_dict[str(a['address{}'.format(i)])]=(a['size{}'.format(i)],a['value{}'.format(i)])
print(new_dict) 
#{'65500': (2, 23.4), '65535': (2, 45.7), '65': (0, 1), '535': (0, 0)}
```